# How to take the attribute value from multiple elements not just the first match

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

How can I take all data-id from the following line of code

**HTML:**

```
<div data-id='1' class="userId">
    <span> user name-1 </span>
</div>
<div data-id='2' class="userId">
    <span>user name-2</span>
</div>
```

**javascript:**

```
var userIds = $('.userId').attr("data-id");
```

But it returns only **1**

Comment: And do what with it?  Return an array?

Comment: Maybe look at the each() function: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Don't edit to ask a new question. I rolled it back. ask a new question. thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var userIds = $('.userId').map(function(){
    return $(this).data('id');
}).get();
```

**How does it work?**

it grabs all the `userId` class elements, then it will execute a function(with `map`) that will return the `data-id` attribute using `data` and then get the results with `get.

**Why doesn't your code work?**

```
var userIds = $('.userId').attr("data-id");
```

`attr` works only on the first matched element in the set, so it returns only the first element id- `1`.

[attr:](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) *Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements...*

Comment: I misread the question; I thought OP was trying to get the first result, not stating that they are having trouble getting _all_ the values. D'oh!

Comment: @gdoron -- thanks for the help and descripton for the answer.. it working fine for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var ar = [];
$('div[data-id]').each( function() {
    ar.push($(this).data('id'));
});
```

...should do it, but I didn't test it.